# Understanding `apply-templates` matching

Tags: xslt

Am I correct in thinking that an `apply-templates` declaration should match **all** templates which could possibly be applied for a selection?

For example, given the following xml fragment:

```
<doc>
  <foo bar="1" baz="2">boz</foo>
</doc>
```

and the following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="foo" mode="xyz" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template mode="xyz" match="foo[bar='1']">
  abc
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template mode="xyz" match="foo[baz='2']">
  def
</xsl:template>
```

I would expect the output to be:

```
abc
def
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you don't get both outputs, as only one template will be selected.
See [this page](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#conflict) for the rules on conflict resolution if there are multiple possible templates.

After fixing your stylesheet (similarly to how Rubens did it, but with same modes), this usually will result in the last template in your xslt file to be applied, so the output will be `def`. This is because the two templates have the same priority and if your xslt processor does not stop with an error the standard requires it to apply the last one:

> It is an error if this leaves more than one matching template rule. An XSLT processor may signal the error; if it does not signal the error, it must recover by choosing, from amongst the matching template rules that are left, the one that occurs last in the stylesheet.

Answer (score 4):

If you ***did*** want your templates to match for **both attributes**, then you would just need to adjust the `match` XPATH to select the *attributes* and put the relationship to `foo` in the predicate; rather than having two conflicting templates matching on the `foo` **element** with the same specificity(which have the same priority).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet
   version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="doc/foo"  />
</xsl:template>

<!--When templates match on foo, apply templates for it's attributes -->
<xsl:template match="foo">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
</xsl:template>

<!--Unique template match for the bar attribute -->
<xsl:template match="@bar[parent::foo and .='1']">
  abc
</xsl:template>

<!--Unique template match for the baz attribute -->
<xsl:template match="@baz[parent::foo and .='2']">
  def
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I wanted to do. Unfortunately I can't accept the answer as it doesn't go into the "why". ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you fix that XSLT code (you have some filter problems) and ran it, you should see:

> def

Why? `<xsl:apply-templates />` will match *first* template which satisfies your match condition. If you have two templates, you should to differ than by using that `<xsl:apply-templates>` `mode` attribute, or by using `<xsl:template>` `priority` attribute:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/doc">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="foo" mode="2" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template mode="1" match="foo[@bar='1']">
        abc
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template mode="2" match="foo[@baz='2']">
        def
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```