# How can I wrap XML texts with tags using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I'd like to wrap text nodes and construct them with tags using XSL.
A sample is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
    <section>
        <container>
            aaa
            <box>
                book
            </box>
            bbb
            <box>
                pen
            </box>
            ccc
            <superscript>
                3
            </superscript>
            ddd
        </container>
    </section>
</root>
```

Is it possible to get the result like below?

```
<div>
    <p>aaa</p>
    <div>book</div>
    <p>bbb</p>
    <div>pen</div>
    <p>ccc<span>3</span>ddd</p>
</div>
```

I'm glad if you help me again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to get the result like below?

Yes. Assuming you start with the [copy idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform), you can then add the following:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- these we want to turn into a <div> and then process children -->
<xsl:template match="box | container | section | formula">
    <div>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<!-- if text node but not directly inside <box> -->
<xsl:template match="text()[not(parent::box)]">
    <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </p>
</xsl:template>

<!-- any other text node as-is -->
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template>
```

Note 1: your example XML is not valid XML, but I assume you meant `</container>`, not `</formula>`.

Note 2: the copy idiom will copy everything not matched. If you do not want this, change it to:

```
<!-- remove anything we do not need -->
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
   <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

Edited: corrected a few flaws in the code. It now creates (added space removed for readability) the following:

```
<div>
   <div>
      <p>aaa</p>
      <div>book</div>
      <p>bbb</p>
      <div>pen</div>
      <p>ccc</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks always Abel. I made it!. And I apologize for my wrong tag. And I'd like to get more hints from you. I rewrite my code both XSL and the result that I want. I added `superscript` tag and text `ddd` in XML, How can I write the XSL to get the result like `<p>ccc<span>3</span>ddd</p>`? Is it possible?

Comment: @tara, yes, just add a matching template for `superscript` and you're done. It's probably a good idea to [read up on template matching here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138774/understanding-apply-templates-matching) and [here (on order of evaluation and then some)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531664/in-what-order-do-templates-in-an-xslt-document-execute-and-do-they-match-on-the), as that is [the core of XSLT](http://lenzconsulting.com/how-xslt-works/). Feel free to vote up and [accept my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) if it helped you.